# Arbitrary depth of filter chains

Tags: python, django

I'd like to select articles which have multiple tags;

```
url(r"^tagged/(?P<tags>[+]*\w+)$", views.tagged, name="tagged"),
```

the request acts like "article/tagged/python+django"

In the views.py, determine the length of tags and find qualified articles

```
def tagged(request, tags):
    tags = tags.split("+")
    if len(tags) == 1:
        articles = Article.objects
                          .filter(tags__name=tags[0])

     if len(tags) == 2:
        articles = Article.objects
                          .filter(tags__name=tags[0])
                          .filter(tags__name=tags[1])
    if len(tags) == 3:
        articles = Article.objects
                          .filter(tags__name=tags[0])
                          .filter(tags__name=tags[1]) 
                          .filter(tags__name=tags[2])

    if ...
```

the multiple seems unwieldily, how could I solve the problem with a general function to handle arbitrary length the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to apply the tags one by one:

```
def tagged(request, tags):
    tags = tags.split("+")
    articles = Article.objects.all()
    for tag in tags:
        articles = articles.filter(tags__name=tag)
```